# Autosuggest renderInputComponent - inputProps types of property 'onChange' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm having this Typescript error when using `react-autosuggest` with a custom input styled-component.

> Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible. Type '(event: FormEvent, params: ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent) => void'.

Code:
(note that it's not complete, just relevant portions)

```js
// styled.ts
export const Input = styled.input`
  // styles
`;

// index.tsx
function renderInput(
  inputProps: Autosuggest.InputProps<SuggestionSearch>,
  placeholder: string
) {
  // --> error here
  return <Input {...inputProps} placeholder={placeholder} />;
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const autosuggestRef = React.useRef<
    Autosuggest<SuggestionSearch, SuggestionSearch>
  >(null);

  const onChange = (event: React.FormEvent, { newValue }: ChangeEvent) =>
    setValue(newValue);

  const inputProps = {
    value,
    onChange,
    onKeyPress: onEnterPress,
  };

  return (
    <Autosuggest
      ref={autosuggestRef}
      renderInputComponent={props => renderInput(props, placeholder)}
      inputProps={inputProps}
      // other props
    />
  )
}
```

Not sure how to fix this, as Autosuggest onChange function overrides the base input onChange prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent about all night on this problem myself. It seems that this is a bug. Here is the signature of the `InputProps`:

```js
    interface InputProps<TSuggestion>
        extends Omit<React.InputHTMLAttributes<any>, 'onChange' | 'onBlur'> {
        onChange(event: React.FormEvent<any>, params: ChangeEvent): void;
        onBlur?(event: React.FocusEvent<any>, params?: BlurEvent<TSuggestion>): void;
        value: string;
    }
```

It seems we'll need to create our own `Input` component that take in this type of `onChange` signature or wrap this onChange in the standard onChange.

So, this is my approach:

```js
const renderInputComponent = (inputProps: InputProps<TSuggestion>): React.ReactNode => {
    const onChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      inputProps.onChange(event, { newValue: event.target.value, method: 'type' });
    };
   return <Input {...inputProps} onChange={onChangeHandler} />;
}
```

Two potential bugs:

- Notice that the `event` returned is `React.ChangeEvent` and not the `React.FormEvent`. Minor difference but it can be a problem in runtime if you actually use it and particular enough about the event.
- The returned `params: ChangeEvent` only account for `type` event method. If you want others, like click, esc, etc..., you must supplement your own (via `onKeyUp` for example, and then call `onChange(...{method: 'esc'})

According to doc:

> Note: When using renderInputComponent, you still need to specify the usual inputProps. Autosuggest will merge the inputProps that you provide with other props that are needed for accessibility (e.g. 'aria-activedescendant'), and will pass the merged inputProps to renderInputComponent.

you don't have to do this:

```
renderInputComponent={props => renderInput(props, placeholder)}
```

Simply pass the `placeholder` directly into your `inputProps` and that would be given right back to you in the `renderInputComponent`.

```
  const inputProps = {
    value,
    onChange,
    onKeyPress: onEnterPress,
    placeholder: 'something!`
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the onChange() on the **renderInputComponent** does not trigger the **onSuggestionsFetchRequested**.

If I do not use custom input (via  **renderInputComponent**), then everything works fine - onSuggestionsFetchRequested got triggered and suggestion list showing.

**Main component**:

```
    const MySearchBox: FC<MySearchBoxProps> = (props) => {
    
    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
        placeholder: props.placeholder,
        value: props.value,
        onChange: props.onChange
    };

    return (
        <Autosuggest
            suggestions={props.suggestions}
            onSuggestionsFetchRequested={props.onSuggestionsFetechRequested}
            onSuggestionsClearRequested={props.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
            getSuggestionValue={props.getSuggestionValue}
            shouldRenderSuggestions={(value) => value.trim().length > 2}
            renderSuggestion={(item: ISuggestion) => {
                <div className={classes.suggestionsList}>{`${item.text} (${item.id})`}</div>;
            }}
            renderInputComponent={(ip: InputProps<ISuggestion>) => {
                const params: InputProps<ISuggestion> = {
                    ...ip,
                    onChange: props.onChange
                };
                return renderInput(params);
            }}
            inputProps={inputProps}
            
        />
    );
};

export { MySearchBox };
```

**Custom Input Component**:

```
import React, { FC, ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import useStyles from './searchInput.styles';
import { Input } from '@material-ui/core';

type SearchInputBoxProps = {
    loading?: boolean;
    searchIconName: string;
    minWidth?: number;
    placeHolder?: string;
    onChange?: (e: ChangeEvent, params: { newValue: string; method: string }) => void;
};

const SearchInputBox: FC<SearchInputBoxProps> = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                <SearchIcon />
            </div>

            <Input
                placeholder={props.placeHolder}
                classes={{
                    root: classes.inputContainer,
                    input: classes.inputBox
                }}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    const params: { newValue: string; method: string } = {
                        newValue: e.target.value,
                        method: 'type'
                    };
                    console.log(`e: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
                    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(e, params);
                }}
                //onMouseOut={(e) => alert(e.currentTarget.innerText)}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export { SearchInputBox };
```

**Render Function**:

```
const renderInput = (inputProps: InputProps<ISuggestion>): React.ReactNode => {
    return <SearchInputBox loading={false} onChange={inputProps.onChange} placeHolder={inputProps.placeholder} searchIconName={'search'} {...inputProps.others} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

I just had to cast HTMLElement into HTMLInputElement
Like below

```
const target = e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement
```

Then, it works fine when you do

```
target.value
```